# how to store floating point number into sql database from asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to store the floating point number into sql database, but when I try to store the database asp.net code will convert the orginal number into other.
eg) If I give **1.1** in textbox then it will stored  in database **1.1000000238418579**

When I drag the procedure the following class created.

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="ServiceFee", DbType="Float")] System.Nullable<double> serviceFee,
```

SQL column Datatype

```
   serviceType  float;
```

Comment: Have you considered using decimal?

Comment: no need, because it will added some extra precision.

Comment: `float` has a representation error. It can represent numbers composed of powers of two, including negative ones, so 1.25 or 1.125 will work fine. 1.1, however, does not have an exact representation, so you get some junk at the end.

Comment: I think, the system convert the float to decimal so this problem occur, because If store it directly to the DB no problem.

Answer (score 2):

The closest representation of 1.1 in single-precision floating point is:

```
0 01111111 00011001100110011001101
```

That in decimal is

`1` * `2^(127-127)` * (1 + `(1 / 16 + 1 / 32 + 1 / 256 + 1 / 512 + 1 / 4096 + 1 / 8192 + 1 / 65536 + 1 / 131072 + 1 / 1048576 + 1 / 2097152 + 1 / 8388608)`) = 1.10000002384185791015625

If you "really" want to store 1.1, you have to use decimal.

Answer (score 1):

> Use the decimal data type to store numbers with decimals when the data
>   values must be stored exactly as specified.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187912(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: The SQL allow to store the value, but I think this is asp.net side problem.